# Populate adapter item on completion asynctask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I've been looking around quite a bit but I had no luck so I'd like to have your opinion on this, especially to know if I'm going in the wrong direction.

I have a fragment instantiating an adapter, passing to it an arraylist of objects. The list of objects references other resources which must be retrieved from the server in order to be displayed. So for every object of the arraylist, **inside the adapter**, I call an asynctask to retrieve these information and populate the adapter item.

Unfortunately this results in only the last element of the arraylsit containing all the info, while the other (in my example I only have two elements in the list) is empty. My feeling is that I'm overriding twice the same adapter item, and therefore I only see the last retrieved object.

My adapter uses the ViewHolder design pattern so, in the function getView I instantiate an object of the ViewHolderItem private class, which contains references to all layout elements. I then use this viewHolderItem in all my onPostExecute to populate the adapter item.

This is the code of my ViewHolder item:

```
private static class ViewHolderItem{
    protected Button leaveFeedback, accept, reject;
    protected LinearLayout userInfo, rideInfo, pickupLayout, buttons;
    protected TextView pickupTimeText;
    protected PickupTime pickupTime;
}
```

This is my getView which gathers the view references, setting up the viewholderitem and launches the asynctasks (the lines after the comment retrieve passenger info):

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    // First let's verify the view is not null
    if (view == null) {
        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ride_passenger_item, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();

        viewHolderItem.userInfo = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.user_info);
        viewHolderItem.rideInfo = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ride_info);
        viewHolderItem.buttons = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btns);
        viewHolderItem.leaveFeedback = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.leave_feedback);
        viewHolderItem.pickupLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pickup_layout);
        viewHolderItem.pickupTimeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pickup_time);
        viewHolderItem.accept = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.accept);
        viewHolderItem.reject = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reject);

        // store the holder with the view.
        view.setTag(viewHolderItem);
    }
    else{
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
    }

    final Passengership passengership = passengerships.get(i);

    /** retrieve passenger info **/
    new GetDemand().execute(demandAPI.getDemand());
    new GetPassenger().execute(userAPI.getUser(passengership.getPassenger()));
    new GetRide().execute(rideAPI.getRide());

    /**
     * if we are displaying pending passenger request, proposed by the driver
     * we need to enable the accept reject button
     **/
    if(type.equals(Status.PENDING) && !passengership.isProposedByDriver())
        buildAcceptRejectButtons(passengership);

    this.passengershipID = passengership.getId();
    return view;
}
```

And this is one of my AsyncTask classes:

```
/**
 * Download the JSON of the demand
 */
private class GetDemand extends GetRequest {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerResponseObject serverResponseObject){
        Demand demand = GsonCustomBuilder.getGson().fromJson(
                serverResponseObject.getJSONObject().toString(), Demand.class);
        demand.populateView(viewHolderItem.rideInfo);
    }
}
```

The demand.populateView() basically is a function to which I pass the viewHolderItem containing the view references so that I can fill the info in them.

Comment: Three AsyncTasks per item? Your battery usage must not be too happy... Can you not restructure the API?

Comment: `I call an asynctask to retrieve these information and populate the adapter item.`. What do you mean with adapter item? Before you said you had an array list with objects. You should populate another arraylist with the same size and put the results in there. Then call afapter notifyDatasetChanged.  You save the results in an aray as kotherwise you lose them while scrolling.

Comment: You should give the async tasks an extra parameter `i` as now they do not know for which item they are started and where to put the result when done.

Comment: `viewHolderItem`. You made that a variable of your Activity? Wrong. Make it a local variable for getView(). This will prevent you from using it elsewhere.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your answers and sorry for the confusion. What I meant with that sentence is that the asynctasks are launched within the adapter and I now understand that they can't know which item the data belongs to. So i understand your point. I'm going to try what you said.

For what  concerns the viewHolderItem it's in the adapter, not in the activity.

Comment: @cricket_007 for the time being I can't change the API. In the future I'll merge the requests. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Still you should make it a local variable of getView(). I already told you why.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I wasn't using the Adapter correctly but thanks to @greenapps inputs I managed to solve my issue.

Basically I moved the variable viewHolderItem in the getView function and I now pass it to all my AsyncTasks through the constructor, so they can use it to populate the adapter item once they get the result from the server.

As an example, this is one of my AsyncTask classes after the modifications described above:

```
/**
 * Download the JSON of the demand
 */
private class GetDemand extends GetRequest {

    private int passengershipID;
    private ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;

    public GetDemand(int passengershipID, ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem){
        this.passengershipID = passengershipID;
        this.viewHolderItem = viewHolderItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerResponseObject serverResponseObject){
        Demand demand = GsonCustomBuilder.getGson().fromJson(
                serverResponseObject.getJSONObject().toString(), Demand.class);
        Passengership passengership = passengershipsHashMap.get(passengershipID);
        passengership.setDemand(demand);
        demand.populateView(viewHolderItem.rideInfo);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I have the constuctor which I use to pass to the AsyncTask the viewHolderItem. Finally, in the onPostExecute I use the viewHolderItem to populate the retrieved info.

Comment: This will not do if you have more items then can be seen. At the moment you have only two items you said so both are always visible. But for a test add much more items so the user has to scroll. You will find out that your approach goes wrong then. What you should do instead i already told you in my first comment.